# How to solve this command prompt-python related issue?

Tags: python, command-prompt

I wrote the program in the Python IDLE. But I want to get it from command prompt.

its like a password locker program which I will get the passwords copied easily instead of typing them again and again.

I wrote my code. And I wrote this -->

```
 @py.exe C:\Users\.....path way \pw.py %*
 @pause
```

when I try to get the password through command prompt.
i wrote "pw email"
so i should get email password. I done the environmental change on the system path. So I should get this password easily.

But it says  ->

```
#pw.py is not recognized as an internal or external

@py.exe C:\Users\.....path way \pw.py %*
        - 
syntax error: invalid syntax
```

How can I get this done, help me please?
Since I am beginner, could you tell me in the easiest way?

the whole program is this:

```
#! python3
#pw.py - An insecure password locker program.


@py.exe C:\Users\bilim\AutomateBoringStuff\pw.py %*
@pause


PASSWORDS = {'email': 'F7minlBDDuvMJuxESSKHFhTxFtjVB6',
         'blog': 'VmALvQyKAxiVH5G8v01if1MLZF3sdt',
         'luggage': '12345'}

import sys, pyperclip
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Usage: python pw.py [account] - copy account password')
    sys.exit()
account = sys.argv[1]      # first command line arg is the account name

if account in PASSWORDS:
    pyperclip.copy(PASSWORDS[account])
    print("Password for " + account + " copied to clipboard.")
else:
    print("There is no account named " + account)

# I saved this as pw.py, and also pw.bat on the right path.
```

Comment: I think there is a big confusion in understanding the python operation! Do you want to run the saved python .py file from the terminal ? Is that it ?

Comment: Yes, I want to run it from terminal. And I just want to get copied password, when i type " pw email" or pw blog, it should be copied, when I do ctrl + V, i could be able to paste it

Comment: not sure, it might be you have one space too much in your line and what you wanted to write is

`@py.exe C:\Users\.....path way\pw.py %*` instead of `@py.exe C:\Users\.....path way \pw.py %*` with a space before hte last backslash

or you might try
`@py.exe "C:\Users\.....path way\pw.py" %*` if your path contains spaces.

Comment: no, it doesn't have space, I shared my code , this one: ' @py.exe C:\Users\bilim\AutomateBoringStuff\pw.py %* '

Comment: Looks like you have mixed up _python_ and _batch_  code. Save them separately i.e. save both `@py.exe "C:\Users\bilim\AutomateBoringStuff\pw.py" %*` and `@pause` lines as `pw.bat` file **and** remove those lines from your `pw.py` file.

Comment: Hello JosefZ, no, I did it and it didnt work. I got a warning about pyperclip is not defined, when i did what you said, but thank you for replying.

Comment: it gives that error when i type " pw email" on terminal. But when i type only "pw" it says pw.py is not recognized, but it shows this "Usage: python pw.py [account] - copy account password"